# How to connect excel with IBM Watson

Tags: excel, vba, ibm-watson

I receive a document with questions on a regular basis (I have the answers from previous iterations. the questions are always similar) and I would like to automate the replies.
I am trying to connect an excel sheet to IBM watson so that I can try to teach it to answer the questions.
I am using the code below to connect to watson but I receive the following error and I am not sure why: 
"#ERROR: 401 - {"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}"

I think it has to do with the syntax of my credentials but I cannot find any support examples.

Any help is appreciated.An example would be ideal. Thank you!

```
Function INTENT(query As String) As String
' IBM WATSON conversation service

If Len(query) > 0 Then 'If query is not empty
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, workspaceID As String, workspaceURL As String, authUsername As String, authPassword As String, response As String, body As String

    ' WATSON Conversation Credentials
    **workspaceID = "a53a2519-30c5-47d5-a98b-cac2bf22fc5c"**
    'The API key from the first page of the project

    workspaceURL = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/" + workspaceID + "/message?version=2018–07–10" 'API requests require a version parameter
    **authUsername = "apikey"
    authPassword = "luVydRf_mxwAxvLHu0kFvTnIQMJttDLGnoMYSDkhpCrx"**


    body = "{""input"":{""text"":"" " + Replace(query, Chr(34), "") + " ""}}" 'The user input in JSON format. Also removed double quotes from input

    xmlhttp.Open "POST", workspaceURL, False, authUsername, authPassword
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

    xmlhttp.Send body

    If xmlhttp.Status = 200 Then 'Request success
        response = xmlhttp.responseText
        INTENT = parseINTENT(response)
    Else 'Request fail
        INTENT = "#ERROR: " & xmlhttp.Status & " - " & xmlhttp.responseText
    End If
End If
End Function

Function parseINTENT(text As String) As String
'Parse intent and confidence from JSON response

Dim p1 As Integer, p2 As Integer

p1 = InStr(text, "[{" + Chr(34) + "intent")
p2 = InStr(p1, text, "}]")
parseINTENT = Mid(text, p1, (p2 - p1) + 2)

End Function
```

Comment: This is kind of unrelated but a question and answer component to Watson, is it built in or is it a "built from the ground up" AI model that you need to work on yourself?  I ask because if you want an AI based Q&A service, you should look at Microsoft's QnAMaker.  The doco is sound and the usage is easy and amazing!  Just a thought.  Maybe you're bound to Watson, I don't know.

Comment: ... better yet, create a chat bot. :-)

Comment: Hi Skin, its actually a series of external questionnaires I receive on a regular basis (mostly in word or pdf). I need to reply the questions and send them back in word/pdf back. I have a very large library of responses and the questions (100+) are almost always similar) so I just need to identify the questions and match it with a previous answer. I will look at the QnAMaker as it would be great to be integrated in the MS Office sweet but I want to explore options. IBM Watson looks to have the functionality needed so I would like to have a running version. Thanks for your comments

Comment: The QnAMaker looks great but I cannot find any excel/vba examples similar to watson on how to connect. Would you have any ideas?